# Delete partial records in cosmos

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Need help on deletion having a set of records with a 12 attributes

1. I have a collection item with partition key as year
2. I have around 1 million rows, in that I want to delete the records which as attribute source="ABC" which will have half a million
3. I planned to do it using the stored procedure bulk delete
4. https://azurecosmosdb.github.io/labs/dotnet/labs/07-transactions-with-continuation.html used the bulk delete script

The problem I see is when I try to execute the stored procedure, it ask for 2 inputs

- a) partition  key value
- b) Query

Even if I provide the partition key some value and the query which is not related to supplied partition key value, so it is not deleting based on my where clause query

```sql
select *
from c
where c.source="ABC"
```

How to achieve my scenario?

No records affected after the execution

Comment: Please edit to explain what you mean, by calling a "stored proc bulk delete" - all you provided was a single select, along with a link to a GitHub repo. Note that all details need to be in your question.

Comment: Stored proc execution is scoped to a single logical partition. So you need to call the stored proc for each logical partition key value, clear one partition then move onto the next one. If you are partitioning on year then there won't be that many of them?

Comment: Are you trying to delete all records for a year? Not clear in your question. If so delete by partition key which is in preview is probably a better option. Stored proc may be ok but are super cumbersome to write and debug. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-delete-by-partition-key?tabs=dotnet-example

Answer (score 0):

**Delete partial records in cosmos:**

**Explanation:**

- `DeleteItemsWithNewId` method to delete records with `newId`  value.
- The function `DeleteItemsWithNewId` creates a parameterized query to choose items with a specific **newId** in the search results.
- `DeleteItemsWithNewId` creates a `QueryDefinition` with the constructed query and sets the parameter value.
- The method runs the query and returns the pages of results using a `queryIterator`.
- Using the `DeleteItemAsync` method, it loops through the query results and removes each item from the container.

*Code I have tried with:*

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUrl, AuthorizationKey, new CosmosClientOptions() { AllowBulkExecution = true });
  Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Database database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);
  Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container container = database.GetContainer(ContainerName);
  await DeleteItemsWithNewId(container, 50);
}

private static async Task DeleteItemsWithNewId(Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container container, int targetNewId)
{
  var query = $"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.newId = @newId";
  var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(query).WithParameter("@newId", targetNewId);
  var queryIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Item>(queryDefinition);

  while (queryIterator.HasMoreResults)
  {
    var response = await queryIterator.ReadNextAsync();
    foreach (var item in response.Resource)
     {
       await container.DeleteItemAsync<Item>(item.id, new PartitionKey(item.pk));
     }
  }
}
```

**Output**:

*Count before deletion:*
[image]

*Count after deletion*:
[image]

- This approach is preferable than using `stored procedure` for large collection because `stored procedure` can only run on a single partition of a collection.
- Using `stored procedure` will take numerous calls because it can only operate on one partition of a collection.
- These numerous calls will be determined by the amount of our collection.
- Hence, I used above approach to delete bulk records.